# Проблема с оператором switch, после ввода case 2: выдает ошибки...И вопрос с удалением файла

Tags: c++, файлы, switch, область-видимости

```
            << "         МЕНЮ:\n"
            << ".........................\n"
            << "1.Записать/дополнить файл\n"
            << "   2.Просмотреть файл\n"
            << "     3.Удадить файл\n"
            << "       4.Выйти\n" 
            << "-------------------------" << endl;

        cout << ">>> ";
        cin >> variant;
        do {
            switch (variant) {
            case 1:
                struct Disk {
                    char DiskCode[20];
                    char Singer[20];
                    int NumberOfSongs;


                };
                cout << "Введите количество CD дисков: " << endl;
                cin >> quantity;
                cin.ignore();
                Disk* arr = new Disk[quantity];

                for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                    cout << "Введите код " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                    cin.getline(arr[i].DiskCode, 20);
                    cout << "Введите исполнителя " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                    cin.getline(arr[i].Singer, 20);
                    cout << "Введите количество треков " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                    cin >> arr[i].NumberOfSongs;
                    cin.ignore();

                }

                string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
                ofstream fileOut;
                fileOut.open(MyFileName, ofstream::app);
                if (!fileOut.is_open()) {
                    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
                }
                else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                        fileOut << "Диск №" << i + 1 << "." << endl;
                        fileOut << "Код: " << arr[i].DiskCode << " " << endl;
                        fileOut << "Исполнитель: " << arr[i].Singer << " " << endl;
                        fileOut << "Количество треков: " << arr[i].NumberOfSongs << " " << endl;
                        fileOut << " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -" << endl;
                    }
                }
                fileOut.close();
                break;
            case 2:

                ifstream read;
                read.open(MyFileName, ifstream::in);
                if (!read.is_open()) {
                    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
                }
                else { char ch;
                    while (read.get(ch)) {
                        cout << ch << endl;
                    }
                }
                read.close();
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Удаление файла..." << endl;
                //remove();
                break;


            }

        } while (variant != 4); {
            cout << "Выход из программы..." << endl;
        }


        cout << "Решение индивидуального задания:\n "
            << "..............................." << endl;
            char nameSinger[20];
            cout << "Введите название исполнителя";
            cin >> nameSinger;
            int Sum = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                  if (strcmp(arr[i].Singer, nameSinger) == 0) {
                  Sum++;
              }
            }
            cout << "Количество дисков данного исполнителя: " << Sum << endl;


        return 0;
    }








    **> Обновленный код (работа с индивидуальным заданием через чтение файла):**

        #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>


    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
        int variant;
        int quantity;

        struct Disk {
            char DiskCode[20];
            char Singer[20];
            int NumberOfSongs;


        };

        do {
            cout << "-------------------------\n"
                << "         МЕНЮ:\n"
                << ".........................\n"
                << "1.Записать/дополнить файл\n"
                << "   2.Просмотреть файл\n"
                << "     3.Удадить файл\n"
                << " 4.Индивидуальное задание\n"
                << "       5.Выйти\n"
                << "-------------------------" << endl;

            cout << ">>> ";
            cin >> variant;

            switch (variant) {
            case 1: {
                cout << "Введите количество CD дисков: " << endl;
                cin >> quantity;
                cin.ignore();
                Disk* arr = new Disk[quantity];

                for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                    cout << "Введите код " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                    cin.getline(arr[i].DiskCode, 20);
                    cout << "Введите исполнителя " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                    cin.getline(arr[i].Singer, 20);
                    cout << "Введите количество треков " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                    cin >> arr[i].NumberOfSongs;
                    cin.ignore();

                }

                string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
                ofstream fileOut;
                fileOut.open(MyFileName,ofstream::app);
                if (!fileOut.is_open()) {
                    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
                }
                else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                        fileOut << "Диск №" << i + 1 << "." << endl;
                        fileOut << "Код: " << arr[i].DiskCode << " " << endl;
                        fileOut << "Исполнитель: " << arr[i].Singer << " " << endl;
                        fileOut << "Количество треков: " << arr[i].NumberOfSongs << " " << endl;
                        fileOut << " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -" << endl;
                    }
                }
                fileOut.close();

                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
                ifstream read;
                read.open(MyFileName, ifstream::in);
                if (!read.is_open()) {
                    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
                }
                else {
                    char ch;
                    while (read.get(ch)) {
                        cout << ch;
                    }

                }
                read.close();
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
                cout << "Удаление файла..." << endl;
                remove(MyFileName.c_str());
                break;


            }




            case 4: { cout << "Решение индивидуального задания:\n  "   //Operācija: aprēķināt disku skaitu norādītajam izpildītajam.
                << "..............................." << endl;

                int Sum = 0;
                string nameSinger;
                cout << "Введите название исполнителя: ";
                //getline(cin, nameSinger);  НЕ ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ ЧЕРЕЗ ГЕТЛАЙН
                cin >> nameSinger;
                cin.ignore();



                string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
                ifstream read;
                read.open(MyFileName, ifstream::in);
                if (!read.is_open()) {
                    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
                }
                else {

                    string str;

                    while (!read.eof()) {
                        str = "";                                                      // затираем старое значение переменной str
                        //read >> str;
                        getline(read, str);
                        cout << "str: "<< str;
                    }


                    int i = 0;
                    for (i = str.find(nameSinger,i++); i < str.size(); i = str.find(nameSinger, i + 1)) {
                        //if (strcmp(str, nameSinger) == 0) {
                        cout << i << endl;
                            Sum++;


                    }
                    //cout << Sum << endl;
                }
                read.close();




                cout << "Количество дисков данного исполнителя: " << Sum << endl;

                break;
            }
            }
        } while (variant != 5); 

            cout << "Выход из меню..." << endl;



        return 0;
    }






> **Вынесла массив за пределы кейсов. Выполнение индивидуального через массив**

    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int variant;
    int quantity;

    struct Disk {
        char DiskCode[20];
        char Singer[20];
        int NumberOfSongs;


    };
    Disk* arr;
    do {
        cout << "-------------------------\n"
            << "         МЕНЮ:\n"
            << ".........................\n"
            << "1.Записать/дополнить файл\n"
            << "   2.Просмотреть файл\n"
            << "     3.Удадить файл\n"
            << " 4.Индивидуальное задание\n"
            << "       4.Выйти\n"
            << "-------------------------" << endl;

        cout << ">>> ";
        cin >> variant;

        switch (variant) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "Введите количество CD дисков: " << endl;
            cin >> quantity;
            cin.ignore();
            arr = new Disk[quantity];

            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                cout << "Введите код " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                cin.getline(arr[i].DiskCode, 20);
                cout << "Введите исполнителя " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                cin.getline(arr[i].Singer, 20);
                cout << "Введите количество треков " << i + 1 << "-ого диска: " << endl;
                cin >> arr[i].NumberOfSongs;
                cin.ignore();

            }

            string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
            ofstream fileOut;
            fileOut.open(MyFileName, ofstream::app);
            if (!fileOut.is_open()) {
                cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
            }
            else {

                for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                    fileOut << "Диск №" << i + 1 << "." << endl;
                    fileOut << "Код: " << arr[i].DiskCode << " " << endl;
                    fileOut << "Исполнитель: " << arr[i].Singer << " " << endl;
                    fileOut << "Количество треков: " << arr[i].NumberOfSongs << " " << endl;
                    fileOut << " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -" << endl;
                }
            }
            fileOut.close();

            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {   string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
        ifstream read;
        read.open(MyFileName, ifstream::in);
        if (!read.is_open()) {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        else {
            char ch;
            while (read.get(ch)) {
                cout << ch;
            }

        }
        read.close();
        break;
        }
        case 3: {
            string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
            cout << "Удаление файла..." << endl;
            remove(MyFileName.c_str());
            break;


        }




        case 4: { cout << "Решение индивидуального задания:\n  "   //Operācija: aprēķināt disku skaitu norādītajam izpildītajam.
            << "..............................." << endl;

            char nameSinger[20];
            cout << "Введите название исполнителя: ";
            cin >> nameSinger;
            int Sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                if (strcmp(arr[i].Singer, nameSinger) == 0) {

                    Sum++;
                }
            }

            cout << "Количество дисков данного исполнителя: " << Sum << endl;


        }
        }
    }
              while (variant != 5); {
                  cout << "Выход из меню..." << endl;
              }

          return 0;
    }



введите сюда код
```

Comment: Вот это `cout << "Чтение файла...... " << arr << endl;` что делает? И что такое `arr`?

Comment: Исправила эту часть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да все просто, смотрите - допустим, есть какой-то `MyClass` с конструктором, и код

```
case 1:  
    MyClass m;
    ....
    break;
case 2:
    m.func();
```

Что делать компилятору, какой код - если у вас вдруг приходит 2? Работать с неинициализированным `m`? Вот поэтому такие фокусы - с разделением времени жизни между `case` - запрещены.

*Для компиляции* вам нужно взять тела своих `case` в фигурные скобки, чтоб область видимости ограничить.

```
case 1:
{
    ... ваш код ...

     break;
}
case 2:
{
```

При этом в `case 2` станет не видна

```
string MyFileName = "MyFile.txt";
```

ее надо будет вынести за пределы `switch` (или дублировать во втором `case`).

Код скомпилируется; будет ли он верно работать или нет - вопрос второй, я не смотрел.

А, да. Удаление (закрытого) файла...

```
#include <cstdio>

remove(MyFileName.c_str());
```

Еще можно воспользоваться `remove` из [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove).

На будущее - не надо задавать сразу несколько "разномастных" вопросов в одном.

Comment: Еще вопрос появился... осталось индив задание в конце выполнить - вычислить сколько дисков всего у запрашиваемого исполнителя... но... естественно, тк все в свидче, доступа к массиву нет и не поработать с ним в индивид задании... Доставать из файла данные и с ними работать? Как можно выкрутиться?

Comment: Вытаскивать все, что нужно, за пределы `switch`.

Comment: Вот вопрос что именно вытащить, тк если вытаскивать создание массива, то уже с меню не начнется все, как нужно в задании, появится ввод данных от пользователя до меню...

Comment: Все переменные, которые должны использоваться более чем в одном `case`...

Comment: А можете в моем коде показать, так не совсем понимаю)))

Comment: И данные все полные получается только в файле...

Comment: Не могу. Дело принципа - даже если разжевал, не глотать - сделайте уж хоть это усилие самостоятельно...

Comment: Вынести то получается, но все равно ошибка, тк пользователь может пройти мимо первого пункта меню и массива не будет... Тут остается работать только с данными из файла, а вот тут проблема

Comment: Так это у вас ошибка не синтаксическая, а логическая! Вы же не можете с помощью языка запретить пользователю выбрать 2. Ну если он так делает - выводите "данные еще не готовы, выберите пункт 1" - правда, все это выглядит как в анекдоте "Не выпендривайтесь, Иван Иванович, и слушайте ваши "Валенки""...

Comment: Но не дает компилировать, выдает ошибку все равно(( даже преподаватель смотрела, говорит похоже только через файл создавать...Могу загрузить сюда конечный код, может увидите какой-то выход?:)))

Comment: Сформулируйте **точно** ваше задание (не своими словами, а как оно вам задано) - может, вы просто спрашиваете, как держать микроскоп, забивая гвозди, а не как их забивать...

Comment: Создать структуру - Код диска, название исполнителя, количество треков на диске. Через меню сделать запись и дополнение в файл, чтение из файла, удаление, индивидуальное задание, выход... Индивидуальное задание - вычислить какое количество дисков у указанного исполнителя. Новый код добавила

Comment: Два варианта кода добавила: первый через файл, не вынося массив за кейс, во втором вынесла

Comment: Вот тут - http://vpaste.net/0XOzr - минимально подправленный код. Что именно вас не устраивает, никак не пойму... Сделано не лучшим образом (ну, например, а если в `cin >> nameSinger;` имя два слова? Или длиннее 19 букв), но логика нормальная...

Comment: Только вот похоже без чтения из файла не обойтись... тк теперь все считает, но если еще добавляешь новую запись в файл, то считает только последнюю сделанную запись в массив...

Comment: А так теперь чудесно видит массив)) Тут, как поняла основной проблемой было это инициализация nullptr? А код с использованием файла в задании смотрели, что там может быть не так?)